# How do I use string manipulation to grab certain parts of an input text file?

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

I have an input text file that has 5 lines with a person's first name, last name and their age next to each other such as:

```
Mark Cyprus 21
Elizabeth Monroe 45
Tom McLaugh 82
Laura Fairs 3
Paul Dantas 102
```

how can I grab just their age out of each line using string manipulation?

Comment: Take a look at the my answer. Also remember to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer. This gives you [reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) too :D and also gives due credit to the answerer ;-) Your question history shows that you have never accepted any answer, which is wrong. You take help from answers, then you mark them as accepted, that's how [so] works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) (take a peek at the link, it has an example similar to your need).

Supposing each line of text is read into char array `line`.

```
sscanf(line, "%*s %*s %d", &age);
```

As you are not interested in first name and last name you can use `%*s`, which will allow to *consume* the first and last name literals from the line, and you won't need to assign them to any variable.

Below is a complete code to do the task, assuming you have a text file named "input.txt" containing the texts you have given in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    char line[100];
    int age;
    while(fgets(line, 100, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%*s %*s %d", &age);
        printf("%d\n", age);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
21
45
82
3
102
```

Some links:

- [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)
- [`freopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/)
- [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Comment: Given the question's interest - will mention `"%*s %*s %d", &age` suppresses assignment of the converted strings, meaning there's no need for `first_name` or `last_name` variables/buffers.

Comment: @TonyD was *so* about to post that *exact* format string. upticked.

Comment: I would also add the namespace `std::`  to mark that this function comes from `<cstdio>` and belongs to the c++ std namespace.

Answer (score 2):

In **C++** , the tool that can help you is `std::istringstream`, in include: `#include <sstream>`. It works like this:

```
std::ifstream ifs("mydatafile.txt");

std::string line;
 
while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line from ifs
{
    std::istringstream iss(line); // access line as a stream
    
    std::string column1;
    std::string column2;
    std::string column3;
    
    iss >> column1 >> column2 >> column3; // no need to read further
    
    // do what you will with column3
}
```

What `std::istringstream` does is allow you to treat a `std::string` like an input stream just like a regular file.

The `iss >> column1 >> column2 >> column3` reads the column data into the vaiables.

Comment: I'd argue it's better to say `if (iss >> column1 >> column2 >> collumn3) ...` to check the line contains three whitespace-separated strings - good habit to check.

Comment: That is good point, thanks. I am always kinda lazy with these checks :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("text");
    std::string str;
    while(fin>>str)
    {
        fin>>str;
        fin>>str;
        std::cout<<str<<"\n";
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
21
45
82
3
102
```